# Git push an older commit

Tags: git, github

I have recently made 2 commits to my Github remote branch. Commit 1 is the first one, and commit 2 is the second one. Commit 1 contains some features I worked on. It is ahead of master by 1, but behind by 10. Commit 2 is a mistake a made, which I accidentally pulled from the master without merging commit 1. In commit 2, I have some weird conflicts.

I revered my local repo back to commit 1, but now, I would like to make a new push to my remote branch, so that I can set my remote branch to commit 1, and merge with the master. Now if I push, I get the error message of `tip of your current branch is behind its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes`. I do not want to run git pull again to get the erroneous commit 2. I commit 1 to show up on my remote branch. Should I run `git push -f` in this case?

Comment: I think you can do it with `git push -f`

Comment: Are you the only person working on the remote branch?

Comment: Yes, we have several remote branch, but I am the only one working on That remote branch

Answer (score 0):

you can push your changes forcefully it will delete your commit2, but sometimes **git push -f** is not recommended.

Another approach would be to revert your **commit2** by running **git revert** , this will create a commit(a reverted version of commit 2) and then push that new commit.